# Taking a value from Data Table Column C#

Tags: c#, select, datatable

Such a daft and simple question I know, but I have a dataset, and within that a data table called "CollectionDetails". Within that data table, there will only ever be one row, and there's a column called "Year". I want to select into a string the value from the row for this column.

```
string year = dataset.Tables["CollectionDetails"].Columns["Years"];
```

This accepts "var year" as it doesn't like the string as I guess this is a number that I want to find.

Comment: Are you looking for `Columns["Years"].ToString();`? To Check type add breakpoint, select dataset.Tables["CollectionDetails"].Columns["Years"], right click and select `Quick view` - you will see what's in there.

Comment: Use First, FirstOrDefault().  I wouldn't use ToString() in case you do get more than one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data table contains only one row of column year so first try to read the column of the first row by using `Rows[0]["Year"]`

```
string year = dataset.Tables["CollectionDetails"].Rows[0]["Year"].ToString();
```

Comment: Glad to hear, please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and vote up by clicking up arrow :)

Answer (score 0):

string year = dataset.Tables["CollectionDetails"].Columns["Years"].ToString(); would retreive string from data set

Comment: Seems to accept it at first, but running it produces "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Data.DataColumnCollection.this[string].get returned null."